# python loop between start data and end date

Tags: python

I have problem with making correct loop from start date and end date.

Both of them I got from js in string format.

For example start date `2021-07-31 07:30:00`

End game `2021-10-27`

Then I convert both of them in `datatime`
For example  its how i convert End Date

```
 _endDate = datetime.strptime(_ruccerenceList[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
```

In the loop with  `timedelta` I wanna add days to Start date.

```
 +  dt.timedelta(days=int(_ruccerenceList[2]))
```

`_ruccerenceList[2]`
can be 1-99

So loop must end then `Start date > End Date`

What I try its look funny but first I try just do this

```
while _perData <= _endDate:
```

When try this way

```
                date_array = \
                    (datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + dt.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(int(_ruccerenceList[2]), (_endDate-datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")).days))
                
                for date_object in date_array:


                    print(date_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

But its not working, if for example `_ruccerenceList[2]` is 3, then first loop working fine, but then it just going not per 3 days, but per 1 day.

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have three variables, `start_string`, `end_string` and `delta_string` which correspond to the data you have received.
Then this should do what you want.

```py
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d"
start = datetime.strptime(start_string, FORMAT)
end = datetime.strptime(end_string, FORMAT)
delta = dt.timedelta(days=int(delta_string))
curr = start
while curr <= end:
  print(curr)
  curr += delta
```

With `start_string="2021-07-31"`, `end_string="2021-10-27"` and `delta_string="3"`, this gives the following output:

```
2021-07-31 00:00:00
2021-08-03 00:00:00
2021-08-06 00:00:00
2021-08-09 00:00:00
2021-08-12 00:00:00
2021-08-15 00:00:00
2021-08-18 00:00:00
2021-08-21 00:00:00
2021-08-24 00:00:00
2021-08-27 00:00:00
2021-08-30 00:00:00
2021-09-02 00:00:00
2021-09-05 00:00:00
2021-09-08 00:00:00
2021-09-11 00:00:00
2021-09-14 00:00:00
2021-09-17 00:00:00
2021-09-20 00:00:00
2021-09-23 00:00:00
2021-09-26 00:00:00
2021-09-29 00:00:00
2021-10-02 00:00:00
2021-10-05 00:00:00
2021-10-08 00:00:00
2021-10-11 00:00:00
2021-10-14 00:00:00
2021-10-17 00:00:00
2021-10-20 00:00:00
2021-10-23 00:00:00
2021-10-26 00:00:00
```

Comment: Nice its working, idk why first way for my not working, i just do same thing as you :D

Comment: If you want to find out why it was not working, try copying your code to a new file, then progressively removing bits until you have reached the same code as me. If doing that, you have found the step that bugs, you're good. If not, and you feel that both codes do the same, try starting from mine and then doing the steps you've done in the other direction (ie. going from my basic code to your original code). If you've found the step where it fails, you've found the bug. Otherwise, you have a working piece of code ;)

Answer (score 1):

First idea: don't write long complicated lines of code. Separate things into meaningful variables. That would be much easier to debug, understand and also would work faster. Second, `range` iterates from `start` (first argument of `range`) to `end` (second argument) one by one. `range` also has the third argument `step` which you need to set to iterate with the given step:

```
start_date = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
start = step = int(_ruccerenceList[2])
days = _endDate - datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")).days

date_array = (start_date + dt.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(start, days, step))
```